# Using Flask Routing in GCP Function?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am looking to serve multiple routes from a single GCP cloud function using python. While GCP Functions actually use flask under the hood, I can't seem to figure out how to use the flask routing system to serve multiple routes from a single cloud function.

I was working on a very small project, so I wrote a quick router of my own which is working well. Now that I'm using GCP Functions more, I'd either like to figure out how to use the Flask router or invest more time on my hand rolled version and perhaps open source it, though it would seem redundant when it would be a very close copy of flask's routing, so perhaps it would be best to add it directly to Flask if this functionality doesn't exist.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue? I'm guessing I'm missing a simple function to use that's hidden in Flask somewhere but if not this seems like a pretty big/common problem, though I guess GCP Functions python is beta for a reason?

Edit: 
Abridged example of my hand rolled version that I'd like to use Flask for if possible:

```
router = MyRouter()

@router.add('some/path', RouteMethod.GET)
def handle_this(req):
    ...


@router.add('some/other/path', RouteMethod.POST)
def handle_that(req):
    ...


# main entry point for the cloud function
def main(request):
    return router.handle(request)
```

Comment: Most web frameworks route based on the URL path. Since you can only serve a single path per Google Cloud Function, what are you hoping to use to route the request instead?

Comment: I want to route on the URL path, which I am doing successfully with my hand rolled version. Sorry that wasn't clear. The point is that if the cloud function runs on `example.com/my-function/` I want to ideally use flask to route for `/my-function/a` and `/my-function/b` but am currently using my own as I could figure out how to use Flask's routing to do it on the GCP function, since you aren't running an app but just getting a Flask.request object back. Basically I'd love a function that takes that request object and runs it through Flask's router, though I can't find it.

Comment: Added an example to help clarify

Comment: It sounds like this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51995682/injecting-a-flask-request-into-another-flask-app. I'd stick to the custom routing you have now, or migrate this to being an App Engine app (which now has a Python 3.7 environment which also uses Flask by default)

Comment: Makes sense given the global context of `request` in Flask, was just hoping there was some magic buried that I didn't find. In this case the cloud function is a huge money saver so I'll probably develop out the custom router and stick with the function. Appreciate the time!

Answer (score 2):

Following solution is working for me:

```py
import flask
import werkzeug.datastructures


app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route('some/path')
def handle_this(req):
    ...


@app.route('some/other/path', methods=['POST'])
def handle_that(req):
    ...


def main(request):
    with app.app_context():
        headers = werkzeug.datastructures.Headers()
        for key, value in request.headers.items():
            headers.add(key, value)
        with app.test_request_context(method=request.method, base_url=request.base_url, path=request.path, query_string=request.query_string, headers=headers, data=request.data):
            try:
                rv = app.preprocess_request()
                if rv is None:
                    rv = app.dispatch_request()
            except Exception as e:
                rv = app.handle_user_exception(e)
            response = app.make_response(rv)
            return app.process_response(response)
```

Based on http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/131/

Comment: I get `Error: could not handle the request` if I call handle_this/that.

Comment: im getting the same error, any chance to get feedback on it? i think the problem is related to the route like mine https://us-central1-company.cloudfunctions.net/my-function

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to inspiration from Guillaume Blaquiere's [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-cloud-function-what-i-use-and-why-12bb5d3798e1) and some tweaking I have an approach that enables me to use ngrok to generate a public URL for local testing and development of Google Cloud Functions.

I have two key files, app.py and main.py.

I am using VS-Code, and can now open up app.py press F5, select "Debug the current file". Now I can set breakpoints in my function, main.py. I have the 'REST Client' extension installed, which then enables me to configure GET and POST calls that I can run against my local and ngrok urls.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#app.py

import os
from flask import Flask, request, Response
from main import callback

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test_function():
    return callback(request)


def start_ngrok():
    from pyngrok import ngrok

    ngrok_tunnel = ngrok.connect(5000)
    print(' * Tunnel URL:', ngrok_tunnel.public_url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if os.environ.get('WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN') != 'true':
        start_ngrok()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# This file main.py can be run as a Google Cloud function and deployed with:
# gcloud functions deploy callback  --runtime python38 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated
from flask import Response
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()


def callback(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':  # Block is only for POST request
        print(request.json)
        return Response(status=200)

    return Response(f'''
           <!doctype html><title>Hello from webhook</title>
           <body><h1>Hello! </h1><p>{now:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M}</p>
           </body></html>
           ''', status=200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplified version of @rabelenda's that also works for me:

```
def main(request):
    with app.request_context(request.environ):
        try:
            rv = app.preprocess_request()
            if rv is None:
                rv = app.dispatch_request()
        except Exception as e:
            rv = app.handle_user_exception(e)
        response = app.make_response(rv)
        return app.process_response(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution by [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66026762/3226045) worked for me until I tried calling `request.get_json()` in one of my routes.  The end result was the response being blocked in a lower level due to the data stream already being consumed.

I came across this question looking for a solution using `functions_framework` in Google Cloud Run.  It is already setting up an `app` which you can get by importing `current_app` from flask.

```
from flask import current_app
app = current_app
```

I believe `functions_framework` is used by Google Cloud Functions so it should also work there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @rabelenda's answer above for inspiring my answer, which just tweaks the data/json parameters, as well as enables support for an InternalServerError unhandled exception handler:

```py
import werkzeug.datastructures


def process_request_in_app(request, app):
    # source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55576232/1237919
    with app.app_context():
        headers = werkzeug.datastructures.Headers()
        for key, value in request.headers.items():
            headers.add(key, value)

        data = None if request.is_json else (request.form or request.data or None)

        with app.test_request_context(method=request.method,
                                      base_url=request.base_url,
                                      path=request.path,
                                      query_string=request.query_string,
                                      headers=headers,
                                      data=data,
                                      json=request.json if request.is_json else None):
            try:
                rv = app.preprocess_request()
                if rv is None:
                    rv = app.dispatch_request()
            except Exception as e:
                try:
                    rv = app.handle_user_exception(e)
                except Exception as e:
                    # Fallback to unhandled exception handler for InternalServerError.
                    rv = app.handle_exception(e)
            response = app.make_response(rv)
            return app.process_response(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

@rabelenda's solution is the best. However, with issue of blocking for POST requests a bit refactoring should resolve it.

```
from flask.ctx import RequestContext

def app_dispatcher(request):
  with RequestContext(app, request.environ, request=request):
     try:
         rv = app.preprocess_request()
         if rv is None:
            rv = app.dispatch_request()
      except Exception as e:
         rv = app.handle_user_exception(e)
      return app.finalize_request(rv)
```