# Using URL path variables with Python Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, rest, flask, google-cloud-functions

Has anybody been able to get URL path variables working with Google Cloud Functions written in Python?

Using Flask directly, it's pretty trivial:

```
@app.route('/user/<username>')
def show_user_profile(username):
    return 'User %s' % escape(username)
```

But Google Cloud Functions don't seem to recognize that it needs to pass the "username" param to the function call. Instead, GCF always seems to pass Flask's "Request" object to the function call.

Flask also allows you to access path variables with Request.view_args but that doesn't seem to work on GCP either. It comes in empty.

Has anyone else tried this?

Comment: This may be a duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53488766/using-flask-routing-in-gcp-function/55576232#55576232

Comment: That has to do with having multiple routes. I’m looking for processing variables within the path.

Comment: This one links to the same one, and outlines variables in their url path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59299377/google-cloud-functions-python3-wrapping-http-trigger-functions-with-endpoints#answer-59319482.